# [CleverTap]Campaigns doubts about the products and OS

Tags: clevertap

^_^! Hi all,

In my cleverTap account, there are two products {Product A, Test Product A, Product B, Test Product B}.
And iOS and Android are supported for them.

Now, I create a campaign in Product A, chose iOS and Android in {WHAT do you want to send?}, then let it run.

But, In Product B and iOS platform, I received this notification, is the result is expected, and why?

In my opinion, I created it in Product A, it can be received in Product A not Product B.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of campaigns in CleverTap. Scheduled and triggered.

If its a scheduled campaign the last active device will receive the notification.
If last active device was iOS, it will receive the push notification.  For triggered campaign, the the notification will go to the triggering device.
If the campaign is created on the triggering event “Product A”, then the device performing the triggering event will receive the push notification.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1. Do you mean the scheduled campaign that does not distinguish which product it is set on? 2. If the triggered campaign, it distinguish which product it is set on? => But, I set the campaign not only scheduled or only triggered. I mix them with them, such as: some time begin, some time end, when user tiggered some operation, push notification.